# Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables

Tags: matlab, equation, symbolic-math

I don't know why first iteration is no problem, but second iteration is error that is:

> Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.

```
%%%%conversion 
syms Z1 Z2 Z3 Za Zc C L 
for i = 1:2   
    % T-pi conversion
    Z11 = 2*Z1 +Z3 == (Za + Zc)^2/(2*(Za+Zc));
    Z21 = Z3 == (Za^2-Zc^2)/(2*(Za+Zc));
    eqn=[Z11,Z21];
   
    % solve the equation
    f = solve(eqn,[Za,Zc]);
    [Za] = simplify(parallel(Za,C))
    
    % Pi-T conversion
    Z11 = 2*Z1 +Z3 == (Za + Zc)^2/(2*(Za+Zc));
    Z21 = Z3 == (Za^2-Zc^2)/(2*(Za+Zc));
    eqn = [Z11,Z21];
    
    % solve the equation
    [Z1, Z3] = solve(eqn,[Z1,Z3]);
    [Z1] = simplify(serial1(Z1,L))
   
    % after solve equation, Z1,Za is overwritten with a expression, sol of
    % equation?
end
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could copy-paste the full error message, including the part that says exactly where in the code the error happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer        
Here is error command   
Error using sym.getEqnsVars>checkVariables (line 92)
Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.

Error in sym.getEqnsVars (line 56)
    checkVariables(vars);

Error in sym/solve>getEqns (line 429)
[eqns, vars] = sym.getEqnsVars(argv{:});

Error in sym/solve (line 226)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});

Error in T_pi_conversion (line 14)
    [Za, Zc] = solve(eqn,[Za,Zc]);